# Soap messages with DHTMLX Touch

Tags: javascript, soap, dhtmlx

With dhtmlx touch you can send ajax calls with ease like:

```
dhx.ajax().get("some.php","a=1"); //GET: some.php?a=1
dhx.ajax().post("some.php","a=2"); //GET: some.php; POST: a=2;
```

But is there also a possibility to send SOAP requests with dhtmlx?
Something like:

```
var xml = //XML string HERE;
dhx.ajax().post("some.php",xml); //Post SOAP request
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked at it more thorough but it doesn't seem to be possible with the framework. The solution being that I have to create my own calls.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `ajax()` function is the way to go about it. [Have you tried using `dhtmlxService`](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhxwsc%3adhtmlxwebservice)

Here is a great example of the markup:

```
function doInvoke() {
    var ip = document.getElementById("ipaddress").value;
    var service = new dhtmlxService(
        "http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL", "GeoIPService", "GeoIPServiceSoap");
    var response = service.invokel("GetGeoIP", "IPAddress", ip);
    document.getElementById("country").value = response.getValue("CountryName"); 
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm using DHTMLX Touch not DHTMLX. Your solution would work fine, but not in the Touch environment. Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

A SOAP web service is just like a RESTful request in that they are both basically doing an HTTP POST of data to the server.  The difference is that the web service has a lot of extra "stuff" that is required (the SOAP envelope for example).  So,  as long as you can build up the SOAP part of the request programatically within your code, there is no reason that you can't use ajax().post mechanism to call a SOAP web service in **exactly** the way that you have described in your question above.

Comment: My thoughts exactly, but when I try to use this it generates a default parameter namely data: in this data I can put my entire soap message if I want but that is of nu use because the server sees the data parameter and responses as I don't support that.

Comment: i'm not an expert - but try this, it could work: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169106&seqNum=7 (4.71)

Comment: I looked at it a little closer, and it appears that the reason it does not work, is because the ajax object does not have the ability to accept additional http headers, so there is no place to set the SOAPAction for the request.  I think what you could do if you are desparate is create your own ajax object based on the dhx.ajax object, and add the ability to add custom headers yourself. The Ajax object starts on line 2554 of the touchui_debug.js file.